# Tengo problemas con el datetimepicker cuando selecciono alguna fila en el datagridview: "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime"

Tags: c#

Tengo un datagridview que quiero que cuando seleccione alguna información contenida en la tabla de mi base de datos MySQL, me regrese los valores a las respectivas cajas de textos y comboboxes y datetiemepicker, pero recibo esta excepción.

```
System.FormatException was unhandled
  HResult=-2146233033
  Message=String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.
  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
       at System.DateTimeParse.Parse(String s, DateTimeFormatInfo dtfi, DateTimeStyles styles)
       at System.Convert.ToDateTime(String value)
       at Proyecto_final1.Worktable.dgvUsuario_CellContentClick(Object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e) in D:\Manejador de items\Proyecto final1\Proyecto final1\Worktable.cs:line 143
       at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.OnCellContentClick(DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.OnCommonCellContentClick(Int32 columnIndex, Int32 rowIndex, Boolean doubleClick)
       at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCell.OnMouseUpInternal(DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.OnCellMouseUp(DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
       at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)
       at Proyecto_final1.Program.Main() in D:\Manejador de items\Proyecto final1\Proyecto final1\Program.cs:line 19
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException:
```

Por último, aquí dejo mis líneas de código.

Las dos últimas líneas son el Combobox y el datetimepicker respectivamente.

```
txtCont.Text = dgvUsuario[0, dgvUsuario.CurrentRow.Index].Value.ToString();
            txtUsu.Text = dgvUsuario[1, dgvUsuario.CurrentRow.Index].Value.ToString();
            txtNomUsu.Text = dgvUsuario[2, dgvUsuario.CurrentRow.Index].Value.ToString();
            txtDirecUsu.Text = dgvUsuario[3, dgvUsuario.CurrentRow.Index].Value.ToString();
            txtTelUsu.Text = dgvUsuario[4, dgvUsuario.CurrentRow.Index].Value.ToString();
            txtCorreoUsu.Text = dgvUsuario[5, dgvUsuario.CurrentRow.Index].Value.ToString();
            CbNivelSeguri.Text = dgvUsuario[6, dgvUsuario.CurrentRow.Index].Value.ToString();
            DTPIniUsu.Value = Convert.ToDateTime(dgvUsuario[7, dgvUsuario.CurrentRow.Index].Value.ToString());
```

Comment: Carlos ,qué valores tienes en la columna número `7` de tu `DataGridView`

Comment: ahora mismo esta vacio pero de la columna que se extrae es de formato date en la tabla de la base de datos.

Comment: oh ya lo resolvi, al tratar el datetimepicker como un textbox me funciono sin problemas, de cualquier modo muchas gracias y perdona las molestias jeje.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

bueno mi problema era que convertia en formato .todatime y luego lo enviaba como .tostring, al trata el datetimepicke  como un objeto de texto resolvio mi conflicto.
el codigo ahora:

```
txtCont.Text = dgvUsuario[0, dgvUsuario.CurrentRow.Index].Value.ToString();
            txtUsu.Text = dgvUsuario[1, dgvUsuario.CurrentRow.Index].Value.ToString();
            txtNomUsu.Text = dgvUsuario[2, dgvUsuario.CurrentRow.Index].Value.ToString();
            txtDirecUsu.Text = dgvUsuario[3, dgvUsuario.CurrentRow.Index].Value.ToString();
            txtTelUsu.Text = dgvUsuario[4, dgvUsuario.CurrentRow.Index].Value.ToString();
            txtCorreoUsu.Text = dgvUsuario[5, dgvUsuario.CurrentRow.Index].Value.ToString();
            CbNivelSeguri.Text = dgvUsuario[6, dgvUsuario.CurrentRow.Index].Value.ToString();
            DTPIniUsu.Text = dgvUsuario[7, dgvUsuario.CurrentRow.Index].Value.ToString();
```

Comment: Deberías aceptar tu respuesta haciendo click en el ✔️ a la izquierda, debajo de las flechas de votación